# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible while trying to access an element with Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to enter username and password in the following website:
https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/sign-in

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.TheGreatCoursesPlus.com/sign-in')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="sign-in-input"]').click()
```

This gave following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Then I tried to use java script:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sign-in-input')[0].click()")
cmd = "document.getElementsByClassName('label-focus')[0].value = 'abc@abc.com'"
driver.execute_script(cmd)
```

There are no errors but no text is sent to "Email Address" field.

Can someone please guide me on the correct way to enter email address, password and then click "Sign-in".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

...implies that the desired **element was not visible** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) while the *WebDriver* instance was trying to find it.

---

### ElementNotVisibleException

[ElementNotVisibleException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException) is thrown when an element is present on the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), but it is not visible, and so is not able to be interacted with.

---

### Reason

One possitive take away from **ElementNotVisibleException** is the fact that the *WebElement* is **present** within the HTML and this exception is commonly encountered when trying to `click()` or `read` an attribute of an element that is hidden from view.

---

### Solution

As *ElementNotVisibleException* ensures that the *WebElement* is **present** within the HTML so the solution ahead would be two folds as per the next steps as detailed below:

- If you next step is to **read** any attribute of the desired element, then you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set to [visibility_of_element_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  my_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- If you next step is to invoke **`click()`** on the desired element, then you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set to [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "element_xpath"))).click()
  ```

---

### This usecase

The *xpath* you constructed as `//h1[@class="sign-in-input"]` doesn't match any node. We need to create unique *xpath* to locate the elements representing `Email Address`, `Password` and `Sign In` button inducing *WebDriverWait*. The below code block will help you to achieve the same:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.TheGreatCoursesPlus.com/sign-in')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='modal']//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("abc@abc.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='modal']//input[@name='password']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='modal']//button[@class='color-site sign-in-button']").click()
```

Comment: You state, `As ElementNotVisibleException ensures that the WebElement is present within the HTML`. The `ElementNotVisibleException` doesn't ensure the element is present, it's thrown when the element is NOT present.

Comment: @JeffC These are fundamentals and basic principals of Selenium and we have covered all these basic questions in numerous threads. If you still have doubt raise a new question as per your requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @DebanjanB You say the same thing every time I bring something up that is provably wrong. Why? You pretending like I don't know what I'm talking about doesn't prove you right. I stated a fact... can you prove otherwise? What about my statement is incorrect?

Comment: @JeffC It's not only about you _...don't know..._ but also 1) you losing the privilege to ask question reflects your wrong doings 2) _6,553_ downvotes shows you still don't trust the community 3) `SOreadytohelp` in your profile is a eye wash only.

Comment: @DebanjanB 1. Why do you keep claiming that I lost the privilege to ask questions? I haven't lost any privileges... I just don't have any questions. This is ironic given you just came off of a week long ban. 2. I downvote because answers aren't useful (per the tooltip) including spreading wrong information, like this answer. 3. I'm on here a LOT (probably an hour or more each day) so I see a lot of questions and answers and I've answered and commented on thousands of questions and answers (see my profile stats). I think that speaks for itself as to your comment on SOreadytohelp.

Comment: @DebanjanB You still didn't answer my question... What about my statement is incorrect?

Comment: @JeffC You said _I just don't have any questions_ but you would keep on asking basic and fundamental questions almost on each and every answers, published by contributors as comments. Can you stop doing that and ask a new question instead?

Comment: If you read back, you will see that my first comment was a statement, not a question. It pointed out what was wrong with this answer. Other than responding to your off-topic statements, the only question I've asked here is `What about my statement is incorrect?` and you STILL haven't answered. Why won't you answer the question if it's so basic and fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

**for username use :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input(@type='email')").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input(@type='email')").send_keys( "username" )
```

**for password use :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input(@type='password')").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input(@type='password')").send_keys( "password" )
```

Comment: Still seeing the same error:
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- The first one is timing, it takes some time for the form to appear. You you can use explicit wait to solve it.
- The second one is that the field id in `<input>` tag, not `<h1>` tag, and there are many fields that matches this xpath. I suggest you locate the form holding the fields and use it to locate each field

For the timing issue you can use explicit wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.TheGreatCoursesPlus.com/sign-in')
form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-body"]//form')))

form.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
form.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
form.find_element_by_name('sign-in-button').click()
```

Comment: great. It worked. Except I need to change the last line:
    form.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='modal']//button[@class='color-site sign-in-button']").click()